# Share OWIN Authentication Cookie across two domains connected with one IIS application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, cookies

I want to know, if there is a possibility to share OWIN Authentication Cookie across `domainA.com` and `domainB.com` which both are connected to the same IIS application. What I want to achieve, is when user logs in `domainA.com` and go to `domainB.com` he will be logged in there too. Can I accomplish that without SSO logic?
For now I have configured OWIN cookie authentication:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "AppCookieName",
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/PathToLogIn")
        });
 
        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The login logic we are familiar with is that the user sends a login request to domainA, domianA obtains information from the request and confirms it, and includes the verified cookie in the response.

So if you want to share the owin authentication cookie, the most basic thing is to ensure that the machine keys in domainA and domainB are the same.

1. Configuring OWIN cookie authentication in statup.
2. Redirect to appropriate login page.
   domainA and domainB are different two application, you need to make sure that when user browser either of them, it redirect to appropriate login page. And in one application add app setting key.

   ```
     <appSettings>
         <add key="LoginUrl" value="your login url">
         <add key="LogoutUrl" value="your logout url">
     </appsettings>
   ```
3. Set up machine key. Make sure that domainA and domainB have same machine key. You can generate key from one site in iis and copy it to application config.

   ```
    <system.web>
      <machineKey decryptionKey="B6047E4219F0EF483DCBBAC097AF677E8D199DC1909596DB" validationKey="9E525E30F6D68862E6157607F9E3EB9E17FFCF366B7D6C080622097D5BFCA1E83B993A8B8DB5FAFFB6B0F7BA092BD8948DC0A1F5DF119B606F1965F4DDFF4D5A" />
    </system.web>
   ```

[image]

If you do not use SSO logic, it may be difficult to achieve, SSO is currently the most appropriate and effective method.So I suggest you to use SSO. You can refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to share cookie.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think you misunderstood me a little. I have two domains bind to the same, single IIS application (one server). Please let me know, if you have a solution for this specific case.

Comment: The same site is bound to different domains,it is unlikely to share cookies. Because cookie is distinguished by domain storage.According to the cookie specification, the browser determines whether a website can operate another website cookie based on the domain name.